# Rendering of axis label using LaTex in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

I'm trying to have an antialiased render of all text on my plots using Matplotlib. My plots are exported as pdf files. I allowed all parameters that say *antialiased* in my matplotlibrc file:

```
### MATPLOTLIBRC FORMAT

lines.antialiased   : True         # render lines in antialiased (no jaggies)
patch.antialiased   : True    # render patches in antialiased (no jaggies)
font.family         : serif
font.weight         : normal
font.size           : 12.0
font.serif          : Computer modern, DejaVu Serif, Bitstream Vera Serif,New Century Schoolbook, Century Schoolbook L, Utopia, ITC Bookman, Bookman, Nimbus Roman No9 L, Times New Roman, Times, Palatino, Charter, serif

text.usetex         : True  # use latex for all text handling. The following fonts
text.latex.preamble :  \usepackage{amsmath},\usepackage{pgfplots},\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

text.antialiased : True # If True (default), the text will be antialiased.
                     # This only affects the Agg backend.


mathtext.fontset : cm # Should be 'dejavusans' (default),
                           # 'dejavuserif', 'cm' (Computer Modern), 'stix',
                           # 'stixsans' or 'custom'


axes.unicode_minus  : True    # use unicode for the minus symbol
                           # rather than hyphen.  See
                           # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Character_codes

legend.loc           : best
legend.frameon       : False     # if True, draw the legend on a background patch
legend.framealpha    : 0.7      # legend patch transparency
legend.facecolor     : inherit  # inherit from axes.facecolor; or color spec
legend.edgecolor     : 0      # background patch boundary color
legend.fancybox      : False     # if True, use a rounded box for the
                             # legend background, else a rectangle

figure.autolayout : True  # When True, automatically adjust subplot
                        # parameters to make the plot fit the figure
```

And here follows a minimum non working example that generates an ugly figure:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,1],[0,10], linewidth=2, label = r'I am a line')
leg = plt.legend(title=r'$The_{\text{legend}}$ : ' ,ncol=1)
leg._legend_box.align = 'left'
plt.xlabel(r'$D \text{(mm)}$')
plt.ylabel(r'Arbitrary unit')
plt.savefig('example.pdf')
plt.close()
```

This gives this figure:

[Link to the pdf file, only valid 10 days](https://transfert.u-psud.fr/ns1hp)

[the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huZlI.png)

And when zoomed in we clearly see that the text is really pixelly out of math mode:

[Figure zoomed in on legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EMzs.png)

[Figure zoomed on axis label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzq5V.png)

How could I avoid this ?

Also:

- I know about svg, tikz and pgf export, but I would really like to have a file type that is easy to share with others,
- I cannot switch all text to math mode because of typo rules. On plots, variables have to be rendered as maths objects and text as text ones,
- adding `\usepackage{lmodern, mathtools}` in the LaTex preamble to use Latin Modern instead of Computer Modern does not work. Maybe because Matplotlib does not use LaTex to render the labels when out of math mode.

Comment: Your link to the figure is a png file, so I am not sure that zooming in is actually a problem in the pdf. Could you maybe provide a link to the actual pdf file? Secondly: If you do not want to use tikz/pgf, I guess you can try SVG file format...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added a link to the pdf file, but I don't know how to add a permanent one, that's why I was using png figures. Also, I can't use svg files, I have colleagues that don't know how to open them.

Comment: I posted a question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405861/the-textlegend-legend-is-aliased. Please see the comment(s) from Skilmon for a possible remedy.

Comment: From the code example it seems you are refering to MathText, not Latex. Are you using Latex (i.e. did you miss some `usetex=True` somewhere)? In any case what would be the purpose of `\text`? Usually to get some upright font in mathmode you would use `\mathrm{}`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Following your question, I added all the uncommented lines from my matplotlibrc file :)

Comment: @BillBell I tried the solution from Skilmon and added `\usepackage{lmodern, mathtools}` to my LaTex preamble, but this does not work. The rendering is exactly the same. I also tried to change the size of the police I use, because he says that this might be the issue but none of the text sizes I tried (from 9 to 13 pt) render text properly.

Comment: Your MWE gives the expected result on my computer ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huHE3.png)). A few tests indicate that setting only `font.family: serif` and `text.usetex: True`, while leaving `font.serif` and `mathtext.fontset` unspecified works just fine as well. Can you try that? If it fails, I would suspect that the problem comes from either LaTeX, dvipng, or ghostscript (the dependencies for usetex, according to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html)). In that case you’d have to check that these are correctly installed and up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment of ImprortanceOfBeingErnest,

> Usually to get some upright font in mathmode you would use `\mathrm{}`

I have a working example of the code generating the figure, without changing the matplotlibrc:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,1],[0,10], linewidth=2, label = r'$\mathrm{I \:  am \:  a  \: line}$')
leg = plt.legend(title=r'$The_{\mathrm{legend}}$ : ', ncol=1)
leg._legend_box.align = 'left'
plt.xlabel(r'$D \:  \mathrm{(mm)}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$\mathrm{Arbitrary \: unit}$')
plt.savefig('example.pdf')
plt.close()
```

This is really good for the rendering. But quite ugly in the code, where I always have to be in `\mathrm{}` mode to write, and add `\:` each time I want a space.

Then, my question becomes: Is there a way to avoid using `\mathrm{}` mode and still have a good figure? If not, then I'm quite happy with this.

Comment: In case ImportanceOfBeingErnest doesn't see this, you should ask your question in the question comments.